# Scala lift framework, ajax form that submits multiple values?

Tags: ajax, scala, lift, ajax-forms

I am just getting started with lift and I am now trying to change a normal form to an ajax form but the method `processEntryAdd` is never called.

```
def addUser(xhtml : Group) : NodeSeq = {

    var firstName = ""
    var lastName = ""

    def processEntryAdd() {
        Log.info("processEntryAdd: " + firstName + ", " + lastName)
    }

    SHtml.ajaxForm(
        bind("entry", xhtml,
             "firstName" -> SHtml.text(firstName, 
                 (x) => {
                     Log.info("Setting firstName to " + x); 
                     firstName = x
                 }),
             "lastName" -> SHtml.text(lastName, 
                 (x) => {
                     Log.info("Setting lastName to " + x); 
                     lastName = x
                 }),
             "submit" -> SHtml.submit("Add user", processEntryAdd),
        ))
}
```

Any idea how to achieve what I am trying to do, or why the code above doesn't work.
The values of the two form fields are submitted when the button is pressed and the two local variables `firstName` and `lastName` are set but the function associated with SHtml.submit isn't called.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This question is kind of old, but I recently needed to know this myself, and this is the best solution I've seen so far:

```
ajaxForm(
    bind("entry", xhtml,
         "firstName" -> text(firstName, firstName = _),
         "lastName" -> text(lastName, lastName = _),
         "submit" -> submit("Add user", processEntryAdd _),
    ) ++ hidden(processEntryAdd _)
)
```

By adding the processing to a hidden form element you get to keep the the submit button, without changing any view code.

You can add client side behaviour by having processEntryAdd() return a JsCmd:

```
def processEntryAdd() {
    Log.info("processEntryAdd: " + firstName + ", " + lastName)
    JsRaw("alert('process entry added')")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like an easy solution, going to try soon.

Comment: In the last snippet, there should be an `=` to prevent `processEntryAdd` automatically becoming `Unit`.

Answer (score 1):

In response to this question David Pollak suggested using

"submit" -> SHtml.hidden("Add user", processEntryAdd) ++

on the lift mailing list.

Comment: And that works, but unfortunately doesn't solve the whole problem. A part of the puzzle that I am still missing is re-rendering a part of the page after ajax response.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer, scroll to the bottom, (ignore the first space after <)

http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/ajaxForm

"submit" -> (SHtml.hidden(auth) ++ < input type="submit" value="Login"/>)